# Linearising data plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Consider the following [example data](https://filebin.net/lrl2z4446usvbsgs), which `ListPlot` gives

[image]

Is it possible to show the result in lines that connect nearby points (some "lines" are easily observable from the plot)?

Comment: `FindCurvePath[{{x1, y1},{x2, y2}, ...}]` gives an ordering of the `{xi, yi}` that corresponds to one or more smooth curves. You would need to provide some actual data to see how best to address your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract different curves from a mixed dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256942/how-to-extract-different-curves-from-a-mixed-dataset) Although I think your dataset might me too messy ...